# what will be formatter string for these date string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i am getting date string from a `RSS` feed likes these

```
 1- "Saturday, May 10, 4pm - Wednesday, May 14, 2014, 5pm"
 2- "Wednesday, April 30, 2014, 5 - 6am"
```

can i use `NSDateFormatter` for getting the `NSDate` from these string ?

any anyone help me to solve this ?

**Updated**

```
//
NSString *completeString = @"Saturday, May 10, 4pm - Wednesday, May 14, 2014, 5pm";

NSArray *array = [completeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMM dd, ha"];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:[array firstObject]];

// second date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter2.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMM dd, YYYY, ha"];

NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter2 dateFromString:[array lastObject]];

NSString *thirdString = @"Wednesday, April 30, 2014, 5 - 6am";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter3.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMM dd, YYYY, h - ma"];

NSDate *date3 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:thirdString];

NSLog(@"first date---%@", date1); 
NSLog(@"second date--%@", date2);
NSLog(@"third date---%@", date3);
```

> first date---2000-05-10 10:30:00 +0000
>
> second date--2013-12-25 11:30:00 +0000
>
> third date---2013-12-24 23:36:00 +0000

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: actully , i have no idea . how i should try to solve it . if you can give any idea. how i can solved it.

Comment: those look time _intervals_ rather than _single_ dates.

Comment: You are not getting date string. You are getting string with date range.

Comment: @holex yes correct. actually its two dates added in one.

Comment: As @holex said, these strings contain 2 dates in effect. You should break them up in 2 different dates before actually using NSDateFormatter to do anything on them.

Comment: @Keenle correct. my task is to get the two dates from this range. 
Saturday, May 10, 4pm, 2014.
Wednesday, May 14, 2014, 5pm

Comment: @DonMiguel yes you are right. i am only worried about the year , which is only present in the second date. so how i can filter there is a year present in the date.

Comment: Ok. There is a pattern in this two string that you provided as an example: dash(-) between dates. So you can split the string by this char. Then parse first one to valid date. Second chunk of the string should be checked if it match some regular expression to figure out how much of the date you have specified in it. Then just parse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your upcoming string of date its format for **Saturday, May 10, 4pm** its a  `EEEE, MMM dd, Ha` so first you set that current date format with `EEEE, MMM dd, Ha` then you do what every you want with this string date to convert with new format. for example Bellow;

```
NSString *dateStr = @"Saturday, May 10, 4pm";
// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMM dd, ha"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMm dd, h a"];
NSString *StrTime = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];


NSLog(@" =%@",StrTime);
```

It's OUTPUT IS **Wed, 050 10, 04 PM** from **Saturday, May 10, 4pm**

In to your question that 1. is two string not single date string that you can create like:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", StrTime, StrTime];
```

**UPDATE:**

and for second one  **Wednesday, April 30, 2014, 5 - 6am"** its date format should look like:

```
EEEE, MMM dd, YYYY, h - ma
```

that same you can convert this foarat to other.

Comment: It not `HH` but `h`, `HH` is 24 hour format with leading 0, where `h` is used with AM/PM. Also The question how to go from the string to a `NSDate` which should work with the suggest format, but you will need to add a local because there is english day and month, So add:  `dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];`

Comment: @pawan why should it not? The format is `YYYY`, just don't forget to set the local. If you don't set the local, iOS on none english device will not know how handle the day and month names.